# Add View to RelativeLayout in OnCreate()

Tags: android, android-layout

**EDIT** Please view the bottom of this question where it says **EDIT**. Because i solved the issue by moving the `<com.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView` from the inner layout, to the root layout. But now I still need to get the added child views into the inner layout called "Dress" to get them in the screenshot. Thanks.

I take a screenshot of a RelativeLayout. The screenshot must show only the size of the ImageView that is inside the RelativeLayout. The reason I cannot take a screenshot of the ImageView itself is because I have other child views that get added on top of the ImageView that need to be in the screenshot.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:onClick="deleteImage"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
    tools:context=".DressingRoomActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Dress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <com.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView 
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/CropImageView"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewDress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="#00CED1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My code to take the Screenshot:

```
public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
        View v = findViewById(R.id.Dress);
        v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        return v.getDrawingCache();
    }
```

**EDIT:** I do not get the child views in the screenshot. I used to take a screenshot of the RootView of the activity to get them, but i do not want the actionbar, so I need to take a screenshot of the inner relativeLayout. But as you can see I add the child view to the Rootview like this:

```
photoSorter = new MultitouchImagesView(this.getApplicationContext());
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            addContentView(photoSorter, params);
```

Can I change that to add them to my RelativeLayout called "Dress"?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove padding attribute from your ImageView and Change ScalType to  `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewDress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="#00CED1"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I have now updated the question with what the issue was, and pointing out my new issue. Sorry to change the question now.

Comment: No, I have that. The photoSortr is what I'm not getting in the right layout. I will try and add that via XML now, to my Dress RelativeLayout.

Comment: Ok I don't think that will work as photoSortr is not a view, it just causes all kinds of problems. I need to add it in onCreate like I do but to the RelativeLayout called Dress, not to the root layout.

Comment: instead ` addContentView(photoSorter, params);`  you can use `relLayout.addView(photoSorter, params);`

Comment: Thanks! Annoyingly, when I do that, it makes the black strips appear on the photo again. The photoSorter has params of wrap_content as shown in my question so I have no idea why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

android:padding="10dp" remove this line from your xml imageview code ...

Comment: Thanks, I have now updated the question with what the issue was, and pointing out my new issue. Sorry to change the question now. I did so about the same time as you answered